# The checkbox plugin that I use does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I followed a [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/15/animated-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-svg/) to create animated checkbox. [Demo here](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedCheckboxes/).

I tried to implement the last example of the demo on my webpage. It's almost working but I don't have the nice crossing effect that [they have](http://goldiman.alwaysdata.net/indexJSon.html).

What did I do wrong? I included the CSS files and javascript files?

I have tried to create the svg box (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6OQM.png) directly in the html but it doesn't seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure ? working for me .

Comment: What browser are you using? tympanus is know for creating on the edge versions

Comment: We would need to see your code

Comment: Here my code : http://goldiman.alwaysdata.net/js/main.js   You can find my code related in "function questionSelection(data) "

Comment: could you also provide your html code? maybe extract the relevant parts in a jsfiddle

Comment: http://goldiman.alwaysdata.net/indexJSon.html But I created all the HTML with the javascript in the questionSelection function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the javascript plugin was loaded before I created the elements in html, so it's couldn't know where it has to apply to
What I did to solve the issue is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toto = { "questiontype":"CrossSeveralAnswers"};
    questionSelection(toto)// Create all the html stuff
    include('./js/svgcheckbx.js'); // Apply the script after.
});
```

Thank for everyone help

Answer (score 1):

1) You should change your `form` class to

```
class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross"
```

2) Maybe you should try to load `JQuery` and `Bootstrap` before :

```
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>  
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Used to move the clouds and others annimations -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- My style sheet -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CheckBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<script src="js/svgcheckbx.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

Actually, the problem is that your `JavaScript` code is not creating the svg element (the image is the preview of the working demo) :

[image: preview]

I'm not sure it will fix the whole problem, but I will continue to look for it.
If I find something, I will edit this post.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser , add the ac-cross does not work and was not in the exemple http://i.imgur.com/dKzRn3E.png  , regarding the jquerry was a good idea but it doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: Can you update your demo, so I can try more things on it with firebug/ Chrome inspector ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find the problem. Try updating jQuery, but I don't think it will fix it. Also, I recommend you adding a .htaccess at the server root with `Options -Indexes` inside to avoid people from seeing all the files you have in your server.

Comment: Ok thank for trying anyway ! :) Don't worry about the files on the server, it's a free hosting that I only use for stackoverflow . Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in main.js file. At the moment i dont have tim to debug it but try to load the content on load/ready.

PS. Move initalize main.js from body to head.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I tried to put the content of the function in doc ready but it doesn't seem to work and I moved the main.js in head but the issue is still there, good ideas anyway! :)

Comment: I'll try to do it by myself later.

Answer (score -2):

Hi i saw the demo as well as their page they have explicitly said that this is just a "Proof-of-concept not a solution", moreover they also have stated that this may not work in some browsers. So maybe that's the issue you are facing. Please read this article
[the codepros link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/15/animated-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-svg/)

Comment: i dont think this is the problem, otherwise you shouldn't be able to see it working on their page, but not on yours.

Comment: Its working on my page. What i said was its not intended for all browsers. Since it was stated so in their documentation. And as the others have commented they also have it working. And since he havent provided us with code that he is working on i thought i should let him know there is a possibility of browser compatability.